# How do I sort a dictionary and get a string of the keys in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with sentences which consist of 4 letters. I need to count the occurrences of each letter, then sort the letters by the number of their occurrence and then write the sentence to the appropriate file.

For example, if the letter `T` has the highest number of occurrences, then `A`, `C`, `G` by order, I would like to write the sentence to a file named `TACG`.

I know how to read and write to the file and I've managed to build a dictionary which contains each letter and it's occurrence, the only thing that is left to do is to sort the dictionary and to get the name to the file out of it.

What is the best way to do that in Python?

Comment: Please post your code so we can work off what you already have.

Comment: What do you mean *"sort a dictionary"*? Dictionaries are *unordered*. You should look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), a dictionary subclass that will do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Counter` answer is good, but you originally asked for a dictionary - so here's what I think -

The easiest way to achieve this in my opinion is quite "pythonic" and would go like this:

```
# assuming `d` is your dictionary
order_as_string = ''.join([y[0] for y in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)])
```

This does the following:

(1) `sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` - Return a list of tuple, each of the form (key, value) from the dictionary `d` sorted by the value of each item in `d`. The `reverse=True` makes sure it is sorted in a descending order.

(2) `[y[0] for y in sorted...]` - For each tuple in (1) grab the "key" part (the 0 item of that tuple). Generate a list out of it.

(3) `''.join(...)` - Join all the items in list (2) with an empty string, generating a new string.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can make this a bit nicer by taking advantage that `sorted` already returns a `list` and avoiding the list-comp and `lambda`: `''.join(sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True))` - that way you're using `d`'s own lookup, not building another `list` and not keeping the items as part of the sort (per se)

Comment: `Counter` *is* a dictionary (it subclasses `dict`, under the hood) - try `isinstance(Counter(), dict)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one (short) line with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> "".join([t[0] for t in Counter('TTTTAAACCG').most_common()])
'TACG'
```

Note that, per the documentation for `most_common`:

> Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily

Comment: I had: `''.join(k for k, v in Counter(s).most_common())` :p

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already have your text, in the string variable `'s'`

```
s = 'TACGAGAGCTAGGCAAGCTTGATGCTAGGAA'
letters = set(s)
```

I'd count how many times each of the letters occur in the string, then make a list of tuples, with the format `(letter, count)`.

```
l = [(letter, s.count(letter)) for letter in letters]

>>> l
[('C', 5), ('A', 10), ('T', 6), ('G', 10)]
```

Then simply sort your list by the count.

```
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: i[1], reverse = True)
[('A', 10), ('G', 10), ('T', 6), ('C', 5)]
```

Now that we have our sorted list, just iterate over that to grab the letters and `join` them.

```
filename = ''.join(i[0] for i in sorted(l, key = lambda i: i[1], reverse = True))

>>> filename
'AGTC'
```